Which is compatible react-native carousel snap version to react -native 0.74.1?
"@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.11", i tried this version with react-native 0.74.1 but i have faced some issues "my  server development page goes to blank"and i have this error message from console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array')
    at <static_initializer> (C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\node_modules\react-native-snap-carousel\index.js:13:1)
    at C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\node_modules\react-native-snap-carousel\index.js:7:23
    at loadModuleImplementation (C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:282:19)
    at guardedLoadModule (C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:182:1)
    at metroRequire (C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:91:43)
    at C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\src\components\Banner.js:3:51
    at loadModuleImplementation (C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:282:19)
    at guardedLoadModule (C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:182:1)
    at metroRequire (C:\Users\HUAWEI\workspace\Grabatoz\frontend\grab-frontend\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\req

I want to clear this error or I need to know the compatible version react-native-snap-carousel
for react native 0.74.1
